# Superposition principle for the electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, superposition, linear-systems

I had read somewhere that superposition principle is valid for linear functions, but the electric field is not a linear function, then why is the superposition principle valid for electric field?

Answer (score 1):

The superposition here refers to the superposition of the solutions of linear differential equation. Maxwell equations for electrostatic field are linear so the solutions, which are the electric fields, satisfy the suprposition. Th basic equation relevant for electrostatics is $\nabla \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ which relates the field to a specififc charge distribution (charge density). If you have two charge distributions, $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ the total field $\vec{E}$ will satisfy Maxwell equation for $\rho_1+\rho_2$ which can be split into $\vec{E}_1+\vec{E}_2$ where each one of the two vectors satisfy the equations with $\rho_1$ and respectively $\rho_2$ on the right hand side.